# Gstreamer udpsrc error "reason error (-5)" due to "Invalid JPEG file structure: two SOF markers"

Tags: udp, gstreamer

I am using the following command to receive a UDP stream from a camera over the network:

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=53247 ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink sync=false`

I am able to receive correctly the video stream from the camera during some seconds but then the video stops with the following error message:

```
** (gst-launch-1.0:7888): CRITICAL **: gst_adapter_push: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buf)' failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
Execution ended after 0:00:08.152866431
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The only informations available about the stream are the following:

Data format: UDP packages / JPEG

Picture resolution: VGA (640 x 480)

Frame rate: 30 fps

I managed to get more informations about my error adding the `--gst-debug-level=2`parameter to my command.

The additional warning message displayed is the following:

```
0:00:11.518477156  6569      0x2577940 WARN            videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:3443:_gst_video_decoder_error:<jpegdec0> error: Failed to decode JPEG image
0:00:11.518555417  6569      0x2577940 WARN            videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:3445:_gst_video_decoder_error:<jpegdec0> error: Decode error #60: Invalid JPEG file structure: two SOF markers
0:00:11.519470502  6569      0x2577990 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:11.519569256  6569      0x2577990 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
```

What is the problem with my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem basing my modifications on this article:

[Play two webcams in MJPG format simultaneously using gstreamer](http://blog.petehouston.com/2015/12/24/play-two-webcams-in-mjpg-format-simultaneously-using-gstreamer)

The functioning command is the following (without the debugging options):

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=53247 ! 'image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! autovideosink sync=false
```

The option `do-timestamp=true` was making my video lag after some times so I chose the option `sync=false`